# Cannot use None as a query value error when i try to view page without search query

Tags: django, django-views

I have a working search form in my base.html but when itry to access the listing page without passing a search query i get a "Cannot use None as a query value" error.
views.py

```
def listing(request):

        if request.method == 'GET':
            search =  request.GET.get('search')       
            propertys = Paginator(Property.objects.filter(property_name__icontains =search).order_by('-listed_on'), 2)
            page = request.GET.get('page')
            propertys = propertys.get_page(page)
            nums = "p" * propertys.paginator.num_pages
            return render(request,"listing.html",{"propertys":propertys, "nums": nums, 'search':search})
        else:
            p = Paginator(Property.objects.order_by('-listed_on'), 2)
            page = request.GET.get('page')
            propertys = p.get_page(page)
            nums = "p" * propertys.paginator.num_pages
            return render(request,"listing.html", {"propertys":propertys, "nums": nums})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't search by `None` in that way, but you can simply check first if `search` has a value other than `None` before you actually try it:

Replace

```py
propertys = Paginator(Property.objects.filter(property_name__icontains =search).order_by('-listed_on'), 2)
```

with

```py
if search:
    propertys = Paginator(Property.objects.filter(property_name__icontains =search).order_by('-listed_on'), 2)
```